# javascript reading dom browser console

Tags: javascript, browser, undefined, console.log

I am trying to read the contents of the page using javascript in the console and getting a funny error I think is just the nature of language but unsure why and wondering if someone can help explain.

I am reading a page and trying to grab certain values and throw them in an object.

```
var jooj = document.getElementsByClassName("a group of div's with children");
var toRet = {};
for(var i=0; i<19; ++i) { 
  var roow = jooj[i].getElementsByTagName("td"); 
  for(var j=0; j<roow.length; j = j+2) { 
    var labeltxt = roow[j].getElementsByTagName("label")[0];
    console.log(labeltxt);
    var detailtxt = roow[j+1].getElementsByTagName("img");
    console.log(detailtxt);
  }   
}
```

the error is thrown on the last .getElementsByTagName call.  It says it's undefined with the msg

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined

but I pretty much do the same thing above except access the current element in iteration.  So I am wondering why this reference error?  It is thrown almost immediately, so it doesn't seem like it is halting half way through due to that method or element not being present on a particular iteration.  It seems to halt right away at the fact that getElementsByTagName is not available.  Further I checked the typeof roow[j+1] and its an object, looks just like the one above.  So I am not sure if I can cast it so it picks up on the methods relating to html nodes, or not.

this works.........

```
for(var i=0; i<jooj.length; ++i) { 
    var roow = jooj[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    for(var j=0; j<roow.length; j = j+2) { 
        console.log(roow[j].getElementsByTagName("label")[0]);
    }    
}
```

this doesn't:

```
for(var i=0; i<jooj.length; ++i) { 
    var roow = jooj[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    for(var j=0; j<roow.length; j = j+2) { 
        console.log(roow[j].getElementsByTagName("label")[0]);
        console.log(roow[j+1].getElementsByTagName("img"));
    }   
}
```

Thanks to all in advanced!

Comment: what is variable 'jooj'. you need to do document.getElementsByTagName("td");

Comment: var jooj = document.getElementsByClassName("a group of div's with children");